# Is list comprehension really much slower than str.replace?

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension

I'm testing different versions of string sanitizing and encountered the effect below. What is hard for me to tell if this is really the result of caching as `%timeit` of IPython warns or if this is real. Please advise:

`str.replace`:

```
def sanit2(s):    
    for c in ["'", '%', '"']:
        s=s.replace(c,'')
    return s


In [44]: %timeit sanit2(r"""   '   '    % a % '   """)
The slowest run took 12.43 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 985 ns per loop
```

List comprehension:

```
def sanit3(s):    
    removed = [x for x in s if not x in ["'", '%', '"']]
    return ''.join(removed)


In [42]: %timeit sanit3(r"""   '   '    % a % '   """)
The slowest run took 8.95 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.12 µs per loop
```

This seems to hold for relatively long strings too:

```
In [46]: reallylong = r"""   '   '    % a % '   """ * 1000

In [47]: len(reallylong)
Out[47]: 22000


In [48]: %timeit sanit2(reallylong)
The slowest run took 4.94 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
10000 loops, best of 3: 96.9 µs per loop


In [49]: %timeit sanit3(reallylong)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 ms per loop
```

**UPDATE**: I presumed that `str.replace` also has more or less O(n) complexity, so I expected both `sanit2` and `sanit3` to have about O(n^2) complexity.

I tested cost of `str.replace` depending on string length:

```
In [59]: orig_str = r"""   '   '    % a % '   """


In [60]: for i in range(1,11):
   ....:     longer = orig_str * i * 1000
   ....:     %timeit longer.replace('%', '')
   ....:
10000 loops, best of 3: 44.2 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 131 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 177 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 219 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 259 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 311 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 349 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 398 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 435 µs per loop


In [61]: t="""10000 loops, best of 3: 44.2 s per loop
   ....: 10000 loops, best of 3: 87.8 s per loop
   ....: 10000 loops, best of 3: 131 s per loop
   ....: 10000 loops, best of 3: 177 s per loop
   ....: 1000 loops, best of 3: 219 s per loop
   ....: 1000 loops, best of 3: 259 s per loop
   ....: 1000 loops, best of 3: 311 s per loop
   ....: 1000 loops, best of 3: 349 s per loop
   ....: 1000 loops, best of 3: 398 s per loop
   ....: 1000 loops, best of 3: 435 s per loop"""
```

Looks linear, but I calculated it to be sure:

```
In [63]: averages=[]   


In [66]: for idx, line in enumerate(t.split('\n')):
   ....:     repl_time = line.rsplit(':',1)[1].split(' ')[1]
   ....:     averages.append(float(repl_time)/(idx+1))
   ....:

In [67]: averages
Out[67]:
[44.2,
 43.9,
 43.666666666666664,
 44.25,
 43.8,
 43.166666666666664,
 44.42857142857143,
 43.625,
 44.22222222222222,
 43.5]
```

Yes, `str.replace` is almost perfectly O(n). So on top of iterating over a list of characters to be replaced, `sanit2` should have O(n^2) complexity just like `sanit3` (`x for x in s` => iterate over characters of a string to be replaced, O(n). `...x in ["'", '%', '"']` should be O(n) as well given `list.__contains__` cost. Altogether O(n^2)).

So in reply to `chepner`, yes, `sanit2` does a fixed number of function calls (and few, just 3 in the example), but due to internal cost of `str.replace` it seems like `sanit2` should have similar order of complexity to `sanit3`.

Is the difference all due to the fact that `str.replace` is implemented in C or maybe the function call (`list.__contains__`) also play an important role?

Comment: If you want a fast solution  `reallylong.translate(None,''''%"''')`, itertaing over a string char by char in python is going to be slow, replace happens at the c level.

Comment: Another good example is  `collections.Counter(reallylong)` vs `{c: reallylong.count(c) for c in set(reallylong)}`. The second will easily outperform the first simply because it is happening at the c level.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: perfect! That's what I'll use as practical solution I suppose. However, my goal in this question is learning the reasons behind difference in performance.

Comment: Both calls are O(n), because the set of characters you are replacing is fixed and independent of the length of the input. `sanit2` makes a fixed number of calls to `str.replace`, and `sanit3` makes a linear number of calls to `x in ["'", '%', '"']`, each of which takes O(1) time. The difference between the two is a combination of the number of method calls you make and the amount of work down in C vs in Python.

Comment: @LetMeSOThat4U, it essentially  just comes down to how optimised the c level string operations are. http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm

Comment: Given that the ratio of the run times increases with the input length (2.12ms/975ns is approximately 2; 1.9ms/96microsec is approximately 20), `sanit3` appears to be something strictly slower than O(n); this is likely due to internal memory management due to converting between a string and a list instead of working with string copies.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: turn your comments into answer pls.

Answer (score 0):

`sanit2` makes a fixed number of calls, independent of the length of `s`, to a string method implemented in C.

`sanit3` makes a variable number of calls (one per element in `s`) to `list.__contains__`, which itself uses an O(n), not O(1), algorithm. It also has to construct a `list` object, then call `''.join` on that list.

It's not surprising that `sanit2` is faster.

Comment: I think how just much faster is why the OP is so surprised. str.replace has to check every character in s,  *  the characters to check for, even using a set for lookups and creating the set  once while also increasing the length of the characters to check for would still leave replace hammering the list approach.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: "I think how just much faster is why the OP is so surprised" - precisely. That's what I'm trying to figure out (that it is faster I can see myself, but **why** it is so much faster)

Comment: @chepner: pls see UPDATE.